# Shoelace.style dropdown panel sizing

Tags: html, css, dropdown, shoelace

I am looking for the way to set the shoelace dropdown panel width @100%, similar to the trigger button.
Here is my code ([pen](https://codepen.io/MadeInLagny/pen/yLQOPYy)). Only the trigger button resizes, not the panel.
Any thoughts?

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="dropdown-selection">
    <sl-dropdown>
      <sl-button slot="trigger" caret>Edit</sl-button>
      <sl-menu>
        <sl-menu-item value="cut">Cut</sl-menu-item>
        <sl-menu-item value="copy">Copy</sl-menu-item>
        <sl-menu-item value="paste">Paste</sl-menu-item>
      </sl-menu>
    </sl-dropdown>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
}

sl-dropdown, sl-button, sl-dropdown::part(panel)  {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the menu isn't the child of the `Edit` button. That means that the menu doesn't try to adjust its width to that of the `Edit` button. To fix this issue I changed the `.wrapper` selector to `.wrapper, sl-menu`.

This is the final code.

```css
@import 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@shoelace-style/shoelace@2.4.0/dist/themes/light.css';

.wrapper, sl-menu {
  width: 300px;
}

sl-dropdown, sl-button, sl-dropdown::part(panel)  {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@shoelace-style/shoelace@2.4.0/dist/shoelace.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="dropdown-selection">
    <sl-dropdown>
      <sl-button slot="trigger" caret>Edit</sl-button>
      <sl-menu>
        <sl-menu-item value="cut">Cut</sl-menu-item>
        <sl-menu-item value="copy">Copy</sl-menu-item>
        <sl-menu-item value="paste">Paste</sl-menu-item>
      </sl-menu>
    </sl-dropdown>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the code and explanations